# Docker volume is empty, not picking up any files

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to set up Docker locally (and eventually in production), but right now, I can't even get volumes mounted right.  I have been following [this tutorial](http://blog.osteel.me/posts/2015/12/18/from-vagrant-to-docker-how-to-use-docker-for-local-web-development.html), which is clearly outdated since Docker has been changing so rapidly for the past year, tutorials and git issues can not keep up.

**My question is, where is my index.php file in my docker container? Why isn't it showing up, despite being specified in my volumes directive?** I even enabled autoindex in my nginx config so I could actually see the directory and prove my suspicions.

I'm on Windows 10

Here's my directory tree:

```
myproject/
    -nginx/
        -default.conf (nginx config)
        -Dockerfile
    -docker-compose.yml
    -index.php (trying to hit this in browser)
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html

php:
    image: php:5.6-fpm
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
MAINTAINER My Name <me@example.com>
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Then I run:

```
D:\Projects\myproject> docker-compose up -d (--build if I've made changes)
```

And then I hit localhost and get the nginx welcome page.  But index.php isn't there!  What gives?  Please school me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just checked it with docker v. 1.12.0 and docker-compose v.1.8.0 and it works. At least when it comes to copying file. Please try: `COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Comment: Well it seems like the configuration file is copying just fine, but the index.php file isn't in the html directory.  I enabled autoindex so I could see this happen, and the directory is empty.

Comment: Try to specify the path of your working dir absolutely. BTW you are not exposing the `9000`port to the hosts network interface and better use `depends_on` rather than `links`

Comment: You mean absolute paths for the volumes?  I tried that just now. When I managed to get the syntax right, I had `"D:\Projects\myproject:/var/www/html"` and it still didn't work, same thing, no index.php. I tried using depends_on instead of links, but all I got was `Unsupported config option for nginx: 'depends_on'`.